# Segmentation fault: Dynamic memory allocation for multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I tried to create a multidimensional array dynamically in C but I am getting a segmentation fault!

```
int **arr=malloc(sizeof(int*) *row);
printf("&ar:r%d arr:%d %d\n\n",*arr,arr,arr[0]);
for(i=0;i<row;i++){
    *(arr+i)=malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
    printf("row: %d",arr[i]);
}
printf("\nbase arr: %d",&arr[0][0]);
```

I checked out address of row and allocated memory as required for total elements in column. But still when I access it `arr[i][j]` **it shows different address** [That's why sigsegv].

```
for(i=0;i<row;i++){
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        arr[i][j]=0; //this point
    }
    puts("done");
}
```

AFAIK, `somearr` and `&somearr` is same for 1 dimensional array.
Here it gives arr[0] and *arr address of row 0. but what is arr? why is it different?

[I checked other related questions in Stack Overflow but I don't have those problems and can't solve this still.]

**Any references or links to study the concept will be great.**

Comment: Where precisely are you getting the segfault?  Can you post the console output you get from this code?

Answer (score 2):

```
*(arr+row)=malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
printf("row: %d",arr[row]);
```

Trying to access `*(arr+row)` inside the for loop is the cause of your segfault. Valid indices are from `0` to `row-1`. I'm guessing you meant to use `i` rather than `row`.

```
*(arr+i)=malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
printf("row: %d",arr[i]);
```

Comment: what is arr? how's it different from &arr[0][0] or arr[0]?